# Exit Pop-Up Plugin Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I want a kind of free wordpress plugin in which when a user exit from my website their i want to show a pop-up in which it says following fields-

1.Username
2.Email
3.Feedback Section

It would be really helpfull if you gave me the links of such plugins.

Comment: you can use costume code not any plugin

Answer (score -1):

you can create a custom form and use this function to make it popup when the user is logged out: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_user_logged_in/

and u will put that code only in the logout page, so the popup will appear only there

Comment: Thanks for the query eazy appreciate your time but i want a plugin which itself comes with a functionality and can be editable....

Comment: I don't know any similar plugin, but you can made and easy thing: https://premium.wpmudev.org/project/logout-redirect/ and redirect users to an page with a form create by you, for the form you can use: Contact Form 7 or similar, and in this way it will be easy

Comment: thanks for the query and guidance but i am searching for the plugin which has all this functionality anyone knows about the plugins submit the link